# how to check if the server response is json or not?

Tags: android, json

I have a trouble in my app when I am trying to add some data to the db by registering a user, the problem is if there any error in the php script or it didn't returned json I got an error and the activity forced to stop, while if there are no errors in the php and returned json correctly, everything functions normally, so I want to check the server response to know if its valid or not, so I can avoid the error, here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Register  extends Activity {

    Button back;
    Button register;
    EditText iname;
    EditText iemail;
    EditText ireEmail;
    EditText ipassword;
    EditText irePassword;
    EditText iid;
    EditText iphone;
    EditText iaddress1;
    EditText iaddress2;


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_register = "http://192.168.0.103/perfectdelivery/register.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        iname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        iemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ireEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        ipassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        irePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        iid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        iphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        iaddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        iaddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);

        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        back.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
        register.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);
    }

    View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new NewAccount().execute();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     */
    class NewAccount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = iname.getText().toString();
            String email = iemail.getText().toString();
            String reEmail = ireEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = ipassword.getText().toString();
            String rePassword = irePassword.getText().toString();
            String id = iid.getText().toString();
            String phone = iphone.getText().toString();
            String address1 = iaddress1.getText().toString();
            String address2 = iaddress2.getText().toString();



            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address1", address1));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address2", address2));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register,
                    "POST", params);

            if(json != null) {

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, MainPage.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to create product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: parse it in try catch. If there error it will catch by block and error in the json .. chears..!!

Comment: Assuming the server correctly sets the `Content-Type` header field, you could potentially check for that before attempting to handle the response body. If json is returned, the value should be `application/json`. If an error is returned (which presumably isn't json), it could for example be something like `text/html` or `text/plain`. You should be able to get the headers from the response object of whatever http client/connection you're using.

Comment: @MH. could you write an example code plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per an earlier comment: assuming the server correctly sets the `Content-Type` header field for the response, you could potentially check for that before attempting to handle the response body.

That is, if json is returned, the header value should be `application/json`. If an error is returned (which presumably isn't in json format, otherwise your question would be a moot point), it could for example be something like `text/html` or `text/plain`. Which exactly it is, doesn't really matter, as long as the server response contains different content type values for 'success' and 'error'.

Checking the `Content-Type` header will look somewhat like this:

```
HttpResponse response = ...
Header contentTypeHeader = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Type");
if ("application/json".equals(contentTypeHeader.getValue()) {
    // server returned json
} else {
    // server returned something else, potentially an error
}
```

Up to you to implement the actual behaviour and handle `null` values etc.

Answer (score 1):

when you got the respone in onPostExecute() just try to convert that string into  json object by passing that response in the constructor of JSONObject. see the below code

```
try {
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject("your_output");
} catch (JSONException e) {
     // your output is not in json format
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so, if your output is in JSON format the Object created successfully. other wise it will throw the exception.